# In ArgoCD is it possible to customize the text displayed in the deployment node, for example?

Tags: argocd, argo

So right now it displays the name only. Suppose I want to display some additional fields from the deployment k8s object.

I could not find any information about it. Is it possible?

**EDIT 1**

The deep link idea unfortunately does not work. I added this to my `argocd-cm` map:

```
  resource.links: |
    - url: https://www.google.com
      title: image
      description: xyz
      if: resource.kind == "Deployment"
```

And it works:

[image]

However, in order to be useful, one should be able to template the title and/or description similarly to url. Alas, templating either title or description is not supported.

A workaround could be a hyperlink to something that would show the fields of interest, but the only idea I have is to implement a dedicated web service to handle the url, which seems an overkill to me.

Comment: I don't think this is possible and I would personally advise against it. This would likely confuse users of resources are named differently in ArgoCD vs. Kubectl.

Comment: You could maybe use [Deep links](https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operator-manual/deep_links/) depending on your use case.

Comment: @GaëlJ - please, see **EDIT 1**